# Optical mouse moving cursor on its own

Tags: mouse, mouse-cursor

I have an optical mouse. Apparently is from Weibo but in the mouse definition it doesn't specify the model. I bought it one or two months ago and it was perfectly fine, without any problems.

Now sometimes it is moving the cursor on its own, with no specific direction. It just starts moving randomly and shaking a lot, sometimes it stops. When I move the mouse the cursor stops, I have to lift the mouse and put it on the table again in order to start moving again.

Even in games, sometimes I control a plane in War Thunder and the crosshair just "teletransports" itself to another part of the screen. And not only in games, but also when I do others things like searching things on Google.

I have a mousepad, it has many colors such as white, black and red. Do these colors affect the mouse? It seems that the mouse becomes even more unpredictable when I move it on the mousepad. I put the mouse on wooden table and I experienced the same thing, although with less frequency.

What can I do?

My computer is a HP NOTEBOOK G62 with Windows 7.

Comment: Have you cleaned the mouse sensors?

Comment: you can try to put a plain white sheet of paper on the mouse pad to see if its coloured surface is the problem. I once had the same problem on surfaces which were not one-coloured.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb : Always use PLAIN BLACK or PLAIN DARK COLORED mousepads. Nothing else works well. If you still experience the issue, clean the sensors using a soft cloth, preferably slightly wetted by a glass cleaner. If not, then clean your USB ports (both the mouse and the PC). If it still doesn't work, claim warranty, there's nothing more you can do.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to clean the sensor. Another answer already mentions this, but I want to add some characteristics of the issue I have experienced. It may not be the OP's case, still I think it can help future users with similar problem.

Sometimes I use my mouse on somewhat fluffy surface, it may be fabric like bed sheet. Rarely it behaves like OP's mouse with no apparent reason; I need to move the mouse by an inch to make it stop. Once in a few months the mouse starts to act crazy even on dedicated surfaces and moving it helps only for a moment.

In these cases **every time** I found a hair (or eyelash) stuck under the sensor. I fixed the mouse by simply removing the hair (and I guess the cases when moving my mouse was enough were caused by a loose hair on the fabric at this particular spot).

Comment: The same for a no-name optical mouse with Linux, on a hard melamine desk.  Fluff accumulates on the mouse's sliding pads, and after a few weeks migrates from there to the optical sensor.